# Remove Characters to leave 3 numbers in a textbox, vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to remove all the extra charaters from a line of text I am reading from a website.

"1.TMI IS xxx AND OPERATORS ARE REMINDED TO INCLUDE THE TMI NUMBER"

I wish to remove everything apart from the three "xxx" which would represent a number.

I had considered an array but the result was I ended up with the "1" at the start left in the text box.

Thanks, James

Comment: You could use regular expressions to do that... It' easier, clean and smart.

Comment: simple one line code? **yourText = Regex.Replace(str, "[\d-]{3}", String.Empty)**

Comment: Edit: **Dim result As String = Regex.Match(yourText, "[\d-]{3}").Value**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or as ZeroWorks said, if you'd prefer Regular Expressions:

```
Dim WebText As String = <source here>
Dim RgEx As Regex = New Regex("[0-9]{3}")
Dim m As Match = RgEx.Match(WebText)
Dim Output As Integer

If m.Success Then
    Dim g As Group = m.Groups(1)
    Output = CInt(g.ToString())
End If
```

Please note: I haven't tried this code myself yet. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about....

```
Dim Input = "1.TMI IS xxx AND OPERATORS ARE REMINDED TO INCLUDE THE TMI NUMBER"

Dim StringValue = Input.
    Split("."c).
    Skip(1).
    First.
    Split(" "c).
    Skip(2).
    First

Dim Number = Integer.Parse(StringValue)
```

It will take the 3rd word after the first `.` and parse it as an integer

Answer (score -2):

You can try this:

Let's say you put the text in a string

```
Dim WebText as String = <source here>
Dim c As Integer = WebText.Length
Dim x As Integer
Dim Output As Integer

For x = 0 To c - 1
    If Not (x + 2) >= c Then
        If Char.IsNumber(WebText.Chars(x)) AndAlso Char.IsNumber(WebText.Chars(x + 1)) AndAlso Char.IsNumber(WebText.Chars(x + 2)) Then
            Output = CInt(CStr(WebText.Chars(x).ToString & WebText.Chars(x + 1).ToString & WebText.Chars(x + 2).ToString))
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next
MessageBox.Show(Output.ToString) 'Displaying it in a MessageBox
```

Comment: You're checking every character three times and while it (may) outperform a regex, it's a readability nightmare